# Changed name of /etc

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, virtual-machine, sudo

I made a huge mistake of not paying enough attention while changing some config files in an Ubuntu VM. By missing a space in a file path, I accidentally changed the name of /etc/ to /etc2. As a result, I can't run `sudo` because there is no path `/etc/sudoers`, and now when I try and run `sudo` I also get `sudo: unknown uid 1000: who are you?`

Is there any way I can recover from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, shutdown your VM, create (or use) another one with a Linux distribution, attach the virtual disk to the new one, boot it, mount the faulty VM root file system under `/mnt`, rename `/mnt/etc2` back to `/mnt/etc`, shutdown the VM, detach the disk, reboot the original one, that's it ...